# how to set up multi level authentication in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, authentication, roles

***How to define multilevel Authentication in laravel 5.3***

In this project many role

- Owner
- Admin
- employe
- end user

**I need Full project of laravel 5.3 authentication any one send me code** 
 email id : tukadiyarameshr@gmail.com

Comment: See Policies: https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#creating-policies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication using multiple tables in Laravel 5.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361614/authentication-using-multiple-tables-in-laravel-5-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation for Polymorphic relations given in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) and the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361614/authentication-using-multiple-tables-in-laravel-5-2/37362894#37362894). The answer will help you understand how to make the relations & create the users.

Once, you have understood how **Polymorphic relations** work... Understand this that Authentication will happen using the `User` table only (by **email** and **password**), but you can verify if the user is `Admin`, `Owner` or `Employee` in the following manner

```
public function checkUserRole() {
  if(auth()->user()->profile_type == 'App\Models\Admin') {
    return 'admin';
  } else if(auth()->user()->profile_type == 'App\Models\Owner') {
    return 'owner';
  } else {
    return 'employee';
  };
}
```

Also, to handle user's page flow, you will have to **create Middlewares** and assign them to their **respective routes**, so no one can access the views which are not meant for them.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried like in version 5.2? it will help:
[How to use multi Auth in laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490600/how-to-use-multi-auth-in-laravel-5-2)

i'm not sure if it works in 5.3 but it doesn't looks different